# Why do we still have the [stl] tag in C++ even when STL no longer exists in C++?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

As we already [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library) C++ does not have [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl), but what happens to be [libstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libstdc%2b%2b) or [stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib). I constantly see that people keep using the [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl) tag instead of the more appropriate [libstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libstdc%2b%2b). Why do we still have the [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl) tag in the first place?

Comment: Your post essentially says "people who had to maintain legacy code don't deserve"... You may want to [edit] question to clarify whether you actually mean it or remove possibility of such interpretation.

Comment: [tag:libstdc++] is just *one implementation* of the C++ standard library, there's also a [tag:libc++] tag. If you want to force people to pick one how about the existing [tag:c++-standard-library] tag instead?

Comment: The [Standard Template Library (STL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) is still a thing. There is no justification whatsoever for removing the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let it be known - if you are the type of programmer that gets to play with only the latest and greatest languages, tools and platforms - I envy you greatly. Because I've been programming for... oh... close to 25 years now (ouch) and in that time I've only had tastes of cutting edge stuff. Most of the time, I'm doing things that have been out of fashion for at least 10 years already. Legacy is the name of the game. Legacy is everywhere. Projects do not involve "Oh build me this entirely new thing!". No no, that's far too costly. "This existing thing I have also needs to do this" is far more frequent.

Now I stopped doing C++ programming, but based on my experiences with Java, I am going to make one bold assumption: when you are a C++ programmer doing C++ projects, I bet you run into proper SGI STL usage quite often. Because even though it may be considered legacy... that doesn't mean it disappeared off of the face of the earth. Pre-existing code is everywhere and it is there to stay for quite some time still.

I don't need Stack Overflow to work out new things which are generally quite well-documented with github pages filled with example code, I need Stack Overflow to work out problems with old stuff which the rest of the internet has forgotten about. Problems with SOAP services, other XML-related topics, questions about old versions of frameworks (AngularJS, Spring 3.x, you name it), whatever the current state of software engineering throws at me. You might say "Yeah well upgrade that stuff then!". Guess what... when upgrading from old to new, it is very necessary to have information about the old. Especially the kind you don't find in the documentation... the kind that Stack Overflow excels in.

Even though the old is less valuable or even unwanted, the information about the old only increases in value overtime. So no, let's not get rid of diamonds such as the STL tag. But perhaps the tag description can use a little more polish to describe better what it is not.

Comment: RE: `perhaps the tag description can use a little more polish to describe better what it is not. That is exactly the solution to the problem.` Apart from that,  a very well written and appealing answer. I couldn't agree more. BTW, there are times I code in good old assembly, just for the sake of it ;) I absolutely love the beauty of legacy systems, I guess, I just thought about it in a different way. A very beautiful and convincing reply. Thanks a lot :) Kudos to you